# Использование local без присваивания

Tags: linux, функции, bash

Можно ли использовать `local` таким образом?

```
function foo() {
  while (($# != 0)); do
   local list+="$1 "
   shift
  done

  echo "${list}"
}

foo "$@"
echo "${list}"
```

Вроде бы [всё работает](https://onlinegdb.com/AfEGMrd50), но в `help local` указано только, что можно присваивать значение переменной через `=`, а не `+=`:

> local: local [option] name[=value] ...

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: правильно конечно `local list; while ... list+="....` а минусы тут ставят многие субъективно